# Oracle Rownum cast

Tags: sql, oracle, rownum

I am trying to create a complex view that will be accessed via a linked server in a MS-SQL server. The problem I am having is that the query uses ROWNUM to generate a ROWID.

The generated ROWID has a datatype of NUMBER but this is apparently causing me a problem and if I can get this into a NUMBER(insert size here) It will all be fine. but I am unsure if this is even possible.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW EXAMPLE ("ROW_ID")
AS
SELECT ROWNUM ROW_ID,
FROM
(SUB-QUERY)
```

I am unable to give the full query and column names (work constraints) but here are the returned column types from the query in SQL Developer

[image: column types]

I think the problem is centred around the returned datatype of ROWNUM being Number and not NUMBER(20) or similar length and that this cross-over is the problem I am seeing with regards to the linked server error but if anyone knows different let me know ;)

Comment: What problem is this causing?

Comment: Msg 7356, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The OLE DB provider "MSDAORA" for linked server "LINKEDSERVER" supplied inconsistent metadata for a column. The column "ROW_ID" (compile-time ordinal 1) of object ""VIEWNAME"" was reported to have a "DBTYPE" of 130 at compile time and 5 at run time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use the cast function: `cast( rownum AS NUMBER(10)) as row_id`

```
create or replace view tvv as 
   select cast( rownum AS NUMBER(10)) as row_id 
   from all_objects 
   where rownum < 10;

> desc tvv
 Name              Null?    Typ
 ----------------- -------- ------------
 ROW_ID                     NUMBER(10)
```

Comment: I did this thanks but the same error appears and complaining about ROW_ID 's DataType I have lookd at the returned datatype using SQLDeveloper and this shows that the datatype has not changed and is still set to NUMBER :s

Comment: @Deviland could you post you dml statment. What datatype shows in SQLDeveloper if you create the view from my answer?

Comment: it would appear that even if you choose to cast rownum it will still return a NUMBER datatype.

Answer (score 0):

Not really a good solution but by removing the rownum and working around the problem from a different angle I have removed the error.